# Umbraco code behind doesn´t inherit type name

Tags: umbraco

asax:

```
<%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="NestlePro.CustomGlobal" Language="C#" %>
```

And this class in code behind

[Global.asax.cs content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0k4c.jpg)

The problem is that it doesn´t inherit the name or something else. Can you help me to find where is the problem? I´m not so skilled in .NET & Umbraco

Comment: Which Umbraco version is it? Also, try adding

using Umbraco.Web;

to the code behind.

Comment: If your class is defined in a separate project library add `Umbraco.Web.dll` as a reference and your global should be <%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="**MyProject.CustomGlobal**"` Language="C#" %>

Comment: I´m using Umbraco 7, how can i add Umbraco.Web.dll as a reference?